# Make elasticsearch return only ids of all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, next.js

I need to render static paths for my NextJS application and I need to retrieve all document's ids from elastic. For now I just return an empty _source, but the best thing would be returning only _id fields. Does anybody know how to do that, and if it's even possible?

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation I've read that elasticsearch always returns _index, _type, _id and _score fields, but you can set _source to false to not receive a data from the document. I did:

```
GET <INDEX>/_search?_source=false
```

And it returns only information about the document without it's data.